# Loop not breaking when string inputted

Tags: ruby, loops

So I was just making a random code generator and i added a loop so you can go again without running it again. But apparently when i type in yes at the end it goes again but when i type in no at still goes again.

Here's my code:

```
loop do
puts "Hello. I am a random code generator. PLease type in how many digits you want"
b = gets.chomp.to_i
a = rand *10**b
puts "Your random code is #{a.to_i}"
puts "Would you like to go again?"
x = gets
  if x == 'no'
 break
end
end
```

Comment: Hint: You used `chomp` once, and `gets` twice.

Comment: When you enter the String via 'gets' the second time, you're appending a newline. Thus you need to call chomp again to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loop do
  puts "Hello. I am a random code generator. PLease type in how many digits you want"
b = gets.chomp.to_i
a = rand *10**b
  puts "Your random code is #{a.to_i}"
  puts "Would you like to go again?"
x = gets.chomp
if x == 'no'
    break
  end
end
```